# What is a non decreasing function of several variables?

Tags: probability, functions, monotone-functions

I came across the undefined terminology *nondecreasing function* in an appendix about "useful remarks on probability" in a textbook, "Social and Economic Networks" by Matthew Jackson. Precisely, it is for functions from ${\mathbb R}^n$ into $\mathbb R$ and the subsection was about "domination of distributions".

Here is an example of statement using *nondecreasing functions*:

> Consider two probability distribution $\mu$ and $\nu$ on ${\mathbb R}^n$. We say that $\mu$ *dominates* $\nu$ if $$E_\mu[f] \geqslant E_\nu[f]$$ for every mondecreasing function $f:{\mathbb R}^n\to{\mathbb R}$.

(with - I guess - $E_\mu[f]=\sum_{d\in{\mathbb R}^n}f(d)\mu(d)$)

What is the usual definition of nondecreasing function $f:{\mathbb R}^n\to{\mathbb R}$ in the context of probability/random graphs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Economists tend to be really sloppy with imposing an order on $\mathbb R^n$ (and other product spaces) without being explicit about what it is they mean exactly. Apologies for that.

I suspect Jackson will have made clear what they mean for a function of several variables to be non-decreasing early in the text (probably chapters $1$ or $2$. If I remember correctly, chapter $1$ is all examples).

In any case, my best guess for what this means (and this is relatively common -- see, for instance, [Mas-Colell, et al](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0195073401), which is the standard graduate reference in microeconomic theory) is this:

Let $x,y\in\mathbb R^n$. Say that $x \geq y$ if $x_i \geq y_i$ for all $i=1,\ldots,n$.

$f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is nondecreasing if $x\geq y$ implies that $f(x) \geq f(y)$.

Other order notation that may come up:

$x>y$ if $x_i \geq y_i$, for all $i=1,\ldots,n$, and $x\neq y$.

$x\gg y$ if $x_i > y_i$ for all $i = 1,\ldots,n$.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of probability theory, the functions you are looking for with such property are most likely the [cumulative distribution functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) in the [multivariate case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Multivariate_case).

A useful genveralization of the concept "nondecreasing" for $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is "nondecreasing in each component of $f$".

Comment: I am not sure I understand the answer. Do you mean "nondecreasing function = nondecreasing in each variable" ?

Comment: That's one way of the generalization as it is given in the link in the context of probability theory.